# Run google colab on local python virtual environment

Tags: python, localhost, virtualenv, google-colaboratory

I know how to run google colab instance on local runtime. But this seems to only consider the whole python environment.

What i would like to do is create a local virtual environment, possibly using using pipenv within anaconda, and then connect my colab notebook to that specific virtual environment.

How's that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

```
!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/')
```

Try this, this will download the anaconda environment to google colab. I believe this is a slightly older version of python. Hope I helped, I do not have experience with anaconda but I believe this works!

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

Just activate the virtual environment of your choice, then follow instructions on this page: https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

Basically, after the Colab installation completed, you will start Jupyter notebook with the extension.

In terminal, you will see a localhost url with a token. You will need that URL when you select local runtime in Colab.

Then, the Colab will just run on your virtual environment.